# VB.NET -> Combobox random index

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I have a question regarding comboboxes in VB.net 2010.

In my database I have 4 fields: e.g.:

```
idDetails | DetailsShortCode | Details_Explain | DetailsSortOrder
{autonum}1| DOA              | Death on Arrival| 5
{autonum}2| NDI              | No Display      | 10
{autonum}3| QQA              | In Research     | 4
```

etc..

These values I pull out of the dbase (mySQL) and insert into a `CheckedListBox`.
I display the values as DetailsShortCode & " - " & Details_explain.
I use a [for loop] to create index numbers, because the sort order is based on the Details Sort order. Which means that VB.net gets 'fed' with the results in the following order:

```
idDetails | DetailsShortCode | Details_Explain | DetailsSortOrder
3         | QQA              | " ... "         | 4
1         | DOA              | "...."          | 5
2         | NDI              | " ... "         | 10
```

If i put this in the listbox, the error I shall receive is '3 is an incorrect value for 'index'"
Due to the fact that VB.net expects that the `CheckedListBox` (and also `ComboBox`) index always is in a sequential order, as in 0,1,2,3,4..etc..

The problem is the fact that orders in the database can change, items can change, and I have a field in another table containing a comma separated list of the details selected (e.g. 1;10;14;12;)
This means that 1 always must be the item with PrimaryKey 1, and that the displayed item on that index must always be the same...

so what I need, is to know how I can use the Primary Key as an Index Number, and let VB.Net not throw an error when the Index is in a random order.., or give the items a hidden value (like in HTML and PHP), in which I can just use the [for loop]  indexes..

---

This is the code I use to insert items to the Details CheckedListBox

```
Function LoadComboBoxes(ByVal CB As String)
    Dim SQLtext = ""
    Select Case CB
        Case "Details"
            SQLtext = "Select " & _
                      "idDetails, " & _
                      "DetailsCode, " & _
                      "DetailsExplain, " & _
                      "DetailsSortOrder " & _
                      "FROM Details order by DetailsSortOrder"
Dim i = -1
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQLtext, dbconn)
    connect()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    CLBDetails.Items.Clear()
    While dr.Read
       i += 1
       CLBDetails.Items.Insert(i, .GetString(1) & " - " & dr.GetString(2))
     End While

end select
end function
```

Comment: where did the `CheckedComboBox` come from?  did you write it?

Comment: Show the code where you insert the items in the listbox. I'm pretty sure you don't need the index to insert anything. A simple add (append to the end) or binding to a list should be enought. Also, usualy list items have a Tag property to store the object.

Comment: the CheckedComboBox is actually a CheckedListBox (please excuse my mix up)..
I have this problem with normal ComboBoxes too, but other than the fact that those don't have to support multiple selections, the display-sequence must be user based.., so the problem is still the same, the Index # is messed-up..

Comment: I can't use add since I have to be in control of the Index#.. add  assigns index# by itself, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a DataGridView which should have all the functionality of the CheckedComboBox plus the ability to keep the data intact as column data and allow you to reference the ID column as an ID Column rather than an ID aliased as an Index.

Depending on what a `CheckedComboBox` is (there are lots of these around) and what it inherits from, you should be able to store objects there:

```
Class DisplayItem
     Friend ID as Long

     DetailsShortCode As String

     Details_Explain As String
     DetailsSortOrder As String

   Public Function overrides ToString As String
       ' depending on the CheckedComboBox add column seperators?
       return DetailsShortCode & Details_Explain & DetailsSortOrder 
   End Function
End Class
```

Adding an object such as this to the control lets you retain the PK ref:

```
   ccb.Items(N).ID
```

While the ToString function lets you format the output as desired.  Further, you could create a List(Of DisplayItem) or BindingList(Of DisplayItem) and drive the CheckedComboBox by binding the datasource to the List.  A DGV is still easier...

Comment: I meant a CheckedListBox, which is a standard object in VB.Net, I have to use that because I need the user to define different 'details' about an object.. The problem with a DataGridView (I actually just found out about those 20 days ago..) is that is does not have a function that 'checks' the items in the DGV.. does it?

Comment: yes, you can define a column as a checkbox (or picture or ... lots of stuff)

Comment: ok, that might solve the problem with the CheckedListBox..
But it will not solve my problem with ComboBoxes (which is the same problem, the sort order will change, thus the index# will come in at a random order)..

Can I use the dataReader as datasource for the Combobox? Will it then use the primaryKey as the index#?

Comment: actually, you can add more than just strings to the CLB (see the answer above), but as stated you are just doing what a DGV can do without a special class.  If you check the answer as helpful, you can gain some reputation for yourself and move this off the Unanswered list.